# How can I get my Microsoft Lifecam VX-1000 webcam microphone to work?

Tags: kernel, webcam

How can I get my webcam's (*Microsoft Lifecam VX-1000*) microphone to work?

It uses the *uvcvideo* driver and video quality is perfect on both *Cheese* and Gmail's Video Chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using the Microsoft LifeCam VX-1000 or VX-3000 and are having trouble with your microphone, could you please do the following?

**1.-**

According to the GSPCA, this fix will be included in kernel 2.6.36 and newer. So until Ubuntu uses kernel 2.6.36 or newer, you will need to install the updated drivers yourself.

you can obtain the new kernel [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.36-maverick/)

32 bits : linux-image-2.6.36-020636-generic_2.6.36-020636.201010210905_i386.deb

64 bits : linux-image-2.6.36-020636-generic_2.6.36-020636.201010210905_amd64.deb

Installing required packages

i. RIGHT CLICK on the package , SELECT "Open with GDebi Package Installer".

ii. If there is no error message then CLICK on "Install Package" button.

REBOOT your system and login with the new kernel

**2.-** another option is compile GSPCA :

download the GSPCA driver from the following link and extract it:
[here](http://moinejf.free.fr/)

Then just open a terminal and change to the extracted directory, then run “make” and “sudo make install”.

It is inconvenient, but thats the only option until the kernel includes it by default.
but kernel 2.6.36 is released yesterday so better option is **"3"**

P.D if you need to compile something you need this package installed :

> sudo apt-get install build-essential install linux-headers-'uname -r' linux-source-'uname -r'

Comment: Hi! I haven't tested your module yet, but I've been reading that thread in the forums and it sure looks promising. Do you know if it ever got merged upstream? Seems 2.6.36 was released just yesterday.

Comment: Yeah... I'm testing 2.6.36 from the mainline kernels and it's fixed. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 4):

Click on the 'sound menu' in the panel and go to "Sound Preferences". On the input tab, you should be able to change the device to your webcam. To check it's working talk or tap the microphone, to check that the Input level bars change.

[image: Selecting QuickCam Zoom Webcam as a microphone]

Comment: I proceeded as you said, but the input level bars didn't spring to life. 

I thought it could be because the webcam wasn't "on" (no LEDs lit), so I'm on Gmail Video Chat settings now, I can see the cam's image, but the mic level bars in there aren't moving either.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Other than increasing the "input volume" on that screen I'm afraid not. Hopefully someone else knowledgeable will come along...

Comment: @LeonNardella Please add this information to your question rather than the answer so it doesn't get buried in the comments, thanks!