# Microsoft LifeCam NX-6000 not working in Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit

Tags: 11.10, usb, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Microsoft LifeCam NX-6000 video to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89919/how-do-i-get-microsoft-lifecam-nx-6000-video-to-work)

I am facing some issues with my webcam and I need some help because I have tried everything but I can't get it work.
I have installed libv4l-0 and cheese webcam booth,but my webcam still doesn't work.I have tried to plug it in different usb ports but still nothing.

When I run `dmesg | grep uvc` command in terminal I get this:

> dmesg | grep uvc

```
[   56.343062] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft® LifeCam NX-6000 (045e:00f8)
[   56.343418] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[   56.344165] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   69.528571] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[   69.528694] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  684.265874] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  684.266495] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  684.267117] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : 0 (exp. 26).
[  684.268370] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  684.269370] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  684.269993] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : 0 (exp. 26).
[  983.936746] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[  983.936869] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[ 1310.904475] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Microsoft® LifeCam NX-6000 (045e:00f8)
[ 1310.904817] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[ 1331.600728] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
[ 1331.600851] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 2 on unit 5: 0 (exp. 2).
```

And when I run `lsusb` I get this :

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 045e:070f Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:00f8 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam NX-6000
```

Can anybody help please?